# Append to an existing file

Tags: windows, makefile, nmake

I wrote the following *assertion* in makefile to append to an existing text file. Make file is executed using **nmake** tool.

```
TempFile.txt :
   >> $@ echo Hello World !
   copy /Y ExistingFile.txt+TempFile.txt ExistingFile.txt
```

The above is working but writing an extra character at the end.

> Hi There !
>    Hello World !
>    -

Extra character is not exactly an `-` character but the carriage return character `SUB`. How to avoid it ? Is there any other easy way to append text to an existing file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can append text to the end of an existing file also by using pipes:

```
TempFile.txt :
   >> $@ echo Hello World !
   type TempFile.txt >> ExistingFile.txt
```